# Objective-C - Set Custom Mac Screen Resolution programmatically

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

I want to set custom screen resolution programmatically. I checked many references and found something useful.

[change screen resolution with objective-c](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/change-screen-resolution-with-objective-c/5175)

[Get valid fullscreen resolutions on OS X in Objective-C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930230/method-of-getting-valid-fullscreen-resolutions-on-os-x-in-objective-c-or-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But it is for setting screen resolutions what supported by system.

My Display can support 1920*1080 as default. But by using some apps, I can set 2560*1600 (custom resolution) and set the other custom screen resolutions too.

[image: Custom resolutions]

Is there any way to set custom resolution with Objective C or c++?

Comment: "Is there any way to set custom resolution with Objective C or c++?" - Yes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you for your comment. I saw the availability. but I want to know how. Do you know any way to do it?

Comment: @PassionMobile how you are getting aspect ratio for each resolution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For creating custom resolution, needs to create a file in

> /System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/DisplayVendorID-(DisplayVendorID
>   value)/DisplayProductID-(DisplayProductID value)

Here is [the way](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/290097-guide-108-add-your-custom-retina-hidpi-resolution-for-your-desktop-display/) for it

After creating custom resolutions, you can set it from System References and set it programmatically too.